# WinSCP, .NET library, checksum support

Tags: ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm using the WinSCP .NET library. Occasionally, the session.CalculateFileChecksum() call will throw an exception when a server does not support the checksum functionality.

I'd like to avoid this by first checking whether or not the FTP server supports the call. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this using the .NET library API.

Any thoughts?

Note: I already know I can do this using the WinSCP GUI. Need an API/C# solution.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for that.

All you can do is to try, catch an exception and test its message for:

> Operation not supported.

---

Or you can enable session logging and parse the log file for a response to `FEAT` command, looking for `HASH`, `XSHA1`, `XSHA256`, `XSHA512`, `XMD5`, `MD5` or `XCRC` (that's what WinSCP does internally).

```
> 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910 FEAT
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910 211-Features:
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  MDTM
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  REST STREAM
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  SIZE
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  MLST type*;size*;modify*;
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  MLSD
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  AUTH SSL
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  AUTH TLS
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  PROT
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  PBSZ
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  UTF8
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  CLNT
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  MFMT
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  HASH SHA-1*;SHA-512;MD5
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  EPSV
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910  EPRT
< 2018-10-17 19:16:53.910 211 End
```